# container stop writing logs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging

I have a kubernetes cluster with 3 pod up and running.
I saw they stop writing to their logs when running

kubectl logs test-dvbs8

After I restart one of them its didnt even start writing to the log, the filesystem is not full.
any idea why this might happen?

```
 NAME                                                           READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
    
    test-dvbs8                                    1/1     Running     2          6d4h
    test-jvxsm                                    1/1     Running     0          21m
    test-lk8w5                                    1/1     Running     0          22h
```

the events in describe:

```
events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                    Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                    -------
  Normal  Scheduled  24m   default-scheduler                       Successfully assigned default/test to host01  
  Normal  Pulled     24m   kubelet,host01    Container image "repo-registry.com:1111/repository/test/test:1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    24m   kubelet, host01  Created container test
  Normal  Started    24m   kubelet, host01  Started container test
```

Comment: what if you run with `-f` flag as `kubectl logs -f test-dvbs8`?

Comment: this is the only  that run it has messages from 2 minutes ago

Comment: I am not sure I follow, can you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: test-dvbs8   - is still writing
 test-lk8w5 - stop writing yesterday 
 test-jvxsm(the new pod ) - dont have noting in the log

Comment: Can you access this machine and use the container engine (Docker, Podman...) do see the logs directly?